# Twilio iOS client not passing parmeters on connect

Tags: ios, twilio

Yet another problem with Twilio for me. So, I'm trying to connect with another user with parametes. Here's my code:

```
-(void)connect:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    NSLog(@"The content of dict is%@",[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]);

    NSDictionary *dict = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    for(NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",key);
        NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:key]);
    }

    [self.device connect:dict delegate:self];
}
```

Problem: no matter what I have in NSDictionary nothing gets passed to server. I have tryied with number of parameters, nothing gets passed. Not even `To` parameters, on non of other, custom ones. It works for every other platform, but not for iOS.

What em I missing here? According to docs it should work, connect method is taking NSDictionary as input,
`-connect:(NSDictionary*)params delegate:(id<TCConnectionDelegate>)delegate`, so where should I look?

PS. This is yet another big problem Twilio lib that I had in last few days. Im getting enough of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem was that I was passing NSDictionary with key that had integer value. The -connect method accepts only `<NSString NSString> NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's figure this out. It’s not entirely clear from your code sample what *exactly* you've passed in as arguments so forgive me if I suggest something you might've already tried.

What happens if you try something like this?

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"To": "number_to_dial"};
_connection = [_phone connect:params delegate:self];
```

If this does not work, we can be certain the problem lies in the account, token, or app itself.

[The iOS sample](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client) shows how to pass the dialing parameters, however it’s still the developer’s responsibility to create proper [​TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) that contains the dialing command tags that Twilio recognizes.

*If the call is hitting your server though* without any parameters being passed in, there should be a Twilio `CallSid` available in the `TCConnectionDelegate.connectionDidConnect:` method. If that's the case, I would suggest [contacting support](https://twilio.com/help/contact) with that Sid and we can dig more info from the server to see what parameters are being passed.

Here's how to retrieve the `CallSid`:

```
- (void)connectionDidConnect:(TCConnection *)connection {
    NSString *callsid = [[connection parameters] objectForKey:@"CallSid"];
    ...
}
```

Could you see if you are able to see this callback method being called and try to provide the `CallSid` if possible?

Comment: Code that I've posted is showing me that I have proper formed NSDictionary and im passing it on.

Comment: `if the call is hitting your server though without any parameters being passed in` <- this is exacly whats happening. I will post in the second CIDs for the calls in the Twilio ticket.

Comment: https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap/blob/master/src/ios/TCPlugin.m
I have tested it (added more logs on my local version), params passed to thet -connect method are well formed NSDictionary with content, for example { "phoneNumber": 103 }